# In what context are statements in Java interface definitions executed?

Tags: java, interface, semantics

I'm looking at the definition of [`org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo`](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.maven/maven-plugin-api/2.0/org/apache/maven/plugin/Mojo.java/?v=source):

```
public interface Mojo
{
    String ROLE = Mojo.class.getName();
    [...]
}
```

I'm lost. To my knowledge, Java interfaces are a set of method signatures. So what's this line which looks like a statement doing here? What are the semantics? For example:

- When does that line get "executed"?
- In the context in which that line runs, what does `Mojo` refer to? What is its type?
- In the context in which that line runs, what does `Mojo.class` refer to? I assume its type is `java.lang.Class`?
- In what context can I read that `ROLE` variable? What is the syntax for doing so? What will the variable contain?
- Can I write to that `ROLE` variable?

Comment: `Mojo` is `Mojo`, `.class` is documented, `Mojo.ROLE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the fields of an interface are implicitely public, static and final. So this is the same as writing

```
public static final String ROLE = Mojo.class.getName();
```

It defines a constant, that all the users of the interface can use, as any other constant: `Mojo.ROLE`. This line is executed when the Mojo interface is initialized by the ClassLoader. `Mojo.class` is the Mojo class, indeed of type `java.lang.Class<Mojo>`. Since the package of the class is `org.apache.maven.plugin`, the value of the constant will be `"org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo"`.

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3) for the relevant section of the Java language specification.

Comment: Thanks. So the line is equivalent to writing `public static final String ROLE = "org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo";`? Seems like some pretty pointless use of crazy metaprogramming ...

Comment: It's not pointless. If this constant is supposed to always be the name of the Mojo class, it's both shorter, makes the intent clearer, and allows refactoring the class (change its name or package) without risking to forget changing the value of the constant. You're just not used to the syntax yet, but that will come.

Comment: I'd say compile-time preprocessing would be more appropriate for concerns like that, rather than runtime execution, but I'll defer. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

the variable get defined when class loader loads the class.
interface variables are static final and can be accessed statically by any class that implements the interface.

```
public class MyClass implements Mojo{
   .
   .
   .
}
```

access:

```
public void someMethod(){
  System.out.println(MyClass.ROLE)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All fields in an interface are implicitly static and final. That answers some of your questions:

- The line gets executed during the static execution. That is possibly during compilation, possibly at the launching of the program and possibly when the class loader loads that class. It's a complicated business, but it's the same as all other static fields.
- `Mojo` refers to the interface itself, statically. It is a type itself, so it has no type.
- `Mojo.class` refers to the `java.lang.Class` of Mojo.
- You can read the `ROLE` variable in any class that implements `Mojo`. You can only read it statically, like `Mojo.ROLE`.
- No, the field is final, so you can't write to it. It is intended for constants only.

Answer (score 0):

> - When does that line get "executed"?

Any member of an `Interface` is `static`  and `final` by default, so `String ROLE` (which can effectivly be seen as

```
public static final String ROLE
```

will be initialized, as every static member, when the ClassLoader loads the class (by the first time, the class is referenced).

[JLS - Loading of Classes and Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2)

---

> - In the context in which that line runs, what does Mojo refer to? What is its type?
> - In the context in which that line runs, what does Mojo.class refer to? I assume its type is java.lang.Class?

Mojo is of the type `java.lang.Class<Mojo>`

---

> - In what context can I read that ROLE variable? What is the syntax for doing so? What will the variable contain?

As it is implicit `public static final` you can access it from everywhere by using `Mojo.ROLE` or through the implementing classes by `ClassName.ROLE`. As [Class#getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) says in the java doc, it will contain the full qualified name of the object:

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.Mojo
```

---

> - Can I write to that ROLE variable?

No, you cannot, because it is implicit `final`

[JLS - Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.2)